# How do I download ClojureDocs for Cursive manually in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, intellij-plugin, cursive

I've recently installed the Cursive plugin for IntelliJ IDEA. At first startup, a popup asks whether ClojureDocs examples should be downloaded: [image]

I clicked on "Don't ask me again" by mistake, instead of "Download". This only happens on the first startup of the plugin, so there's no chance of getting the choice again (as explained in the relevant [documentation](https://cursive-ide.com/userguide/documentation.html#clojuredocs-support)).

How do I get this installed? As I'm fairly new to the language and environment, I find the examples of great help.

- I've searched for a setting that would allow the plugin to ask again, or to initiate the download - no success.
- I've tried to disable then enable the plugin (including restarts of the IDE) - no success.
- I've tried to uninstall then reinstall the plugin (including restarts of the IDE) - no success. It seems to remember the old setting.

I imagine removing some configuration file or option would do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This applies to IntelliJ IDEA version 2020.3 and Cursive version 1.10.0-2020.3 - the Cursive plugin has already been installed and is active.

On menu go to `File > Settings`, in Settings `Language & Frameworks > Clojure`, heading `Documentation Options`, click <kbd>Update</kbd>.

[image]